# Append html string as a table row (<tr>) via javascript-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append an HTML string to

```
var field = '<input type="text" name="featureName" class="form-control" id="featureName" placeholder="Feature Name" value="">'
var jfield = $(field);
$('#featureContainer').append(jfield);
```

When the button is clicked it will crete a input field, but if I click again it creates the input in the same row.
How can I make a new row with the input in it?

The following is my HTML code

```
<tr>
    <td id="featureContainer"></td>
</tr>
```

If I click the button for the second time it creates it in the same row.
I want it to create it in new row.

Comment: "New row" or "next row"?

Comment: Where's the click event code? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: What you've just posted will append all the inputs inside the TD (you're saying new row, it's not even appending it to a new column).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we don't know wether `tr`s are wrapped inside `table` or `tbody`, .... We have to look for the closest `tr` and then get its parent then append a new row to that parent.

So, you should replace this:

```
$('#featureContainer').append(jfield);
```

with:

```
$('#featureContainer').closest('tr').parent().append('<tr><td>' + field + '</td></tr>');
```

**NOTE:** that inside `field` you have a static ID which will be on all the inputs you spawn which will be wrong since IDs are unique. So you may want to assign diferent IDs for diferent inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the html code into `field` variable, like below:

```
var field = "<tr><td id="featureContainer"><input type="text" name="featureName" class="form-control" id="featureName" placeholder="Feature Name" value=""></td>
</tr>"
var jfield = $(field);
```

Assuming there is a button with `id = 'add'` and a table with `id='data'`, then you can add this after above code:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#data').append(jfield);
});
```

Comment: you may want to also change featureContainer to the table.

Comment: @nycynik Yupp.. forgot to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your on the right track. But you don't need the jfield.

this appends the value of 'field' inside the `td` element:

```
$('#featureContainer').append(field);
```

but what you want is to append inside the table. So give your table a `id` (or the tbody) and do the following:

You need to embed the field inside a `<tr><td>` section and append that as a whole.

```
var field = var field = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="featureName" class="form-control" id="featureName" placeholder="Feature Name" value=""></td></tr>';
```

then in the click event:

```
$('#tableid').append(field);
```

Comment: How does this answer put a second click's contents onto a new row?

Answer (score 1):

First **the `id` should be unique in the same document** so better to use a common classes instead, then you could use `append()` to add new row (including `tr/td`), check the example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#add-row').on('click', function(){
  var field = '<input type="text" name="featureName" class="form-control" placeholder="Feature Name" value="">'

  $('table').append('<tr><td>'+field+'</td></tr>');
  
  console.log($('table tr').length+' rows');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Default row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id='add-row'>Add row</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thr issue with your code is that you are trying to append to an element using id selector. Since in a valid html there should be only a single element with an unique id, you will be appending the new element always to the same **td#featureContainer**.

I will suggest you to change the id to class. To select the **td.featureContainer** where you need to append the new element, you can check  inside the clicked button element event handler and find the td.featureContainer

```js
$(".feature").on("click", function() {

  var field = '<input type="text" name="featureName" class="form-control" id="featureName" placeholder="Feature Name" value="">'
  var jfield = $(field);
  $(this).parent().prev(".featureContainer").append(jfield);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="featureContainer"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="feature" value="click for row one">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="featureContainer"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="feature" value="click for row two">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There's no problem using an `id` based selector. The real problem is that the `append` is happening to a row when the answer should be to append an entire row to the table. In that case, using an `id` applied to the `table` would be just fine.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i am not sure if OP wants to add a new row, his current code will append the input element to td#featureContainer.  Although he did said new row but the code example says differently.